# Проблема с входом с помощью selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Цель: Залогиниться на сайте с авторизацией гугла.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


opts = Options()
opts.add_argument('start-maximized')
opts.add_argument('disable-infobars')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/AddSession/identifier?service=accountsettings&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmyaccount.google.com%2F%3Fhl%3Dru%26utm_source%3Dsign_in_no_continue&hl=ru&csig=AF-SEnaAqQc0PuTbyQHT%3A1585861306&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=AddSession')
elem = driver.find_element_by_name('identifier')
elem.send_keys("mymail")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Проблема: Когда бот отправляет майл, то вылетает следующее окно:[image: Окно]

Comment: User-agent передали?

Comment: @Mattern Да, пробовал даже рандомные. Безуспешно.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте избавиться от инфобара, уведомляющего, что используется ПО для автоматизации следущим путем. Возможно, гугл из-за этого ругается.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: Не помогло, все также не впускает